# Pandas dataframe groupby using unique combinations

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, pandas-groupby

I am trying to groupby and take unique combinations only, However it's returning repeated values and it's impacting my calculations

Problem:

| child | parent | Year | Month | Val | desc |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| GC1 | p1 | 2021 | 1 | 100 | group1desc |
| GC1 | p1 | 2021 | 1 | 100 | group1desc |
| GC2 | p1 | 2021 | 1 | 200 | group1desc |
| GC2 | p2 | 2021 | 2 | 200 | group2desc |
| GC2 | p2 | 2021 | 2 | 200 | group2desc |
| GC3 | p2 | 2021 | 2 | 300 | group2desc |
| GC3 | p2 | 2021 | 2 | 300 | group2desc |

When I use `DF.groupby(['parent', 'year', 'Month'], as_index=False).agg({'val':'sum','desc':'first', 'child':list})`

It gives:

| parent | Year | Month | Val | desc | child |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| p1 | 2021 | 1 | 400 | group1desc | GC1,GC2 |
| p2 | 2021 | 2 | 1000 | group2desc | GC2,GC3 |

What I want is unique vals only, i.e. GC1 added one for P1 and P2 = GC2 + GC3 (added once)

| parent | Year | Month | Val | desc | child |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| p1 | 2021 | 1 | 300 | group1desc | GC1,GC2 |
| p2 | 2021 | 2 | 500 | group2desc | GC2,GC3 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's try with [`unique`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.unique.html) + [`sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.sum.html) for `Val` and just `unique` for `child`:

```
g = (
    df.groupby(['parent', 'Year', 'Month'], as_index=False)
        .agg({'Val': lambda s: s.unique().sum(),
              'desc': 'first',
              'child': 'unique'})
)
```

`g`:

```
  parent  Year  Month  Val        desc       child
0     p1  2021      1  300  group1desc  [GC1, GC2]
1     p2  2021      2  500  group2desc  [GC2, GC3]
```

---

DataFrame Constructor (`df`):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'child': ['GC1', 'GC1', 'GC2', 'GC2', 'GC2', 'GC3', 'GC3'],
    'parent': ['p1', 'p1', 'p1', 'p2', 'p2', 'p2', 'p2'],
    'Year': [2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021],
    'Month': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2],
    'Val': [100, 100, 200, 200, 200, 300, 300],
    'desc': ['group1desc', 'group1desc', 'group1desc', 'group2desc',
             'group2desc', 'group2desc', 'group2desc']
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This works fine and gives the desired results.
Just wanted to check what are the implications on performance when i have to apply this calculation for at least 6+ fields in same data frame and 100k + records

Comment: Hi Henry, This solution was working until I encountered scenario where GC1 = 100 and GC2 = 100 & GC2 = 100 this solution ends up taking just 100 as values. I need GC1 + GC2 = 200 in those cases. Can you suggest how to incorporate such cases in this. Thanks for your help

Comment: I would say that dm2's answer is what you're looking for. But don't subset `drop_duplicates`. `df.drop_duplicates().groupby(['parent', 'Year', 'Month'], as_index=False).agg({'Val': 'sum', 'desc': 'first', 'child': list})`

Comment: If you do end up using that solution would you un-accept this answer? As I've misunderstood the subsetting of unique values.

Answer (score 1):

Since your 'desc' aggregation is 'first', you could just drop duplicates before the groupby:

```
df.drop_duplicates(subset = ['child','parent','Year','Month'])\
.groupby(['parent','Year','Month'], as_index = False)\
.agg({'Val':'sum','desc':'first','child':list})
```

Output:

```
    parent  Year    Month   Val desc        child
0   p1      2021    1       300 group1desc  ['GC1', 'GC2']
1   p2      2021    2       500 group2desc  ['GC2', 'GC3']
```

Comment: Good eye, thought I'd borrow that improvement from your answer but didn't quite get it :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. 
I tried it in larger dataset and it wipes away the common numbers and the end result is not as expected.